# Excel Parameters to SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, excel, vba

I have had a look on the old faithful google and I cant quite find the scenario I am looking for.  I am currently wanting to pass a number of work orders from a cell through a SQL statement in my work sheet but I cant get it to work with multiple parameters.

My TSQL statement is something like this

```
select * from Order where OrderNo IN ('GNR1','GNR2')
```

I want to put the parameters `GNR1` and `GNR2` etc. in to a cell "`A1`" in my excel work book and bring back the necessary records, I have no problem with just one parameter but passing more than 1 I am struggling with, can anyone offer assistance.

I am using SQL Server 2012 and Excel 2010

Comment: I would agree that allowing the user to enter the values across multiple cells and then reformat them to pass through to the sql but unfortunately they could have any number of values from 1 to 151, I will work through your suggestions and try to make them work...thank you for the valuable suggestions

Comment: I have been playing around a you suggested by getting a user to enter the orders in to specific cells and then reformatting them as a normal In statement in SQL, but when running the code I get the String Data, right truncation error from the SQL Server Drive the parameter that I am trying to pass when formatted looks like ('GNR68003054', 'GNR68003055') so there should be no problem, any ideas why this is happening??

Answer (score 0):

You will need to replace `'GNR', 'GNR2'` with a question mark `?`.  This should allow you to "parameterize" the query.  Cell `A1` will then need to be an exact representation of the string.

It may be helpful to point the parameter `?` to cell `A2` or some other cell or even a cell on a different worksheet.  That is, allow the end user to enter the parameter in a natural way and then do the actual formatting (adding single quotes) elsewhere before you pass it to the query.

Some additional resources: [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office2010developertrainingcourse_vbalab_topic3.aspx) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/197453/run-an-sql-query-with-a-parameter-from-excel-2007)

Answer (score 0):

If you can delimit the values in your cell(s), you can use a string split method and assign those to parameters in your code, and then call your query or stored procedure based on those parameter values. It would be a lot easier as mentioned to separate the parameter values to multiple cells.